# How to implement the functionality of adding to favorites?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to implement the functionality of adding news to favorites, so that when you click on the icon, the news is added to favorites and displayed on a separate page "Favorites". In the project I use GetX. Please tell me how can I do this?
Below is the news code that comes from the API.
I will be grateful for help)

```
class Source {
  String id;
  String name;

  Source({required this.id, required this.name});

  factory Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Source(id: json['id'], name: json['name']);
  }
}
```

---

```
import 'source_model.dart';

class Article {
  Source source;
  String author;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  String urlToImage;
  String publishedAt;
  String content;

  Article(
      {required this.source,
      required this.author,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.url,
      required this.urlToImage,
      required this.publishedAt,
      required this.content});


  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']),
      author: json['author'] ?? "",
      title: json['title'] ?? "",
      description: json['description'] ?? "",
      url: json['url'] ?? "",
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'] ?? "",
      publishedAt: json['publishedAt'] ?? "",
      content: json['content'] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to just show the favorites to another screen for one time, or do you want to save them permanently in the offline or online database?

Comment: so there are many to do that, one way is from the server they provide you a fav option, true or false, and check that if true then it should be fav and other is not, and there need ba another API which you hit the server as add to fav, then those products would be fav true, you can get, and another way is, you make filed in model name fav then all the data need to cash, hope you understand

Comment: I want to store them in the Firestore database. I have already connected it and I'm all set. I can’t figure out how, when I click on the icon in one news item, add it to a new page and database

Answer (score 0):

To store articles, you'll require a document database. There are multiple options available and all of them depend on your requirements.

If you want to store the favourites only locally, then [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) is a great dart document database that you can use.

If you want the favourites accessible everywhere, then you'll have to store them in a remote database. In that case you can use [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore?gclid=CjwKCAjwrqqSBhBbEiwAlQeqGuG522n6vtZ3_THPZyddjqfLgxBrqxOlJhBmBLNNSzRy7UweEqLZlBoCz-IQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) or create a custom backend functionality for that.

Comment: Yes, I want to store them in Firestore. I have already connected the database to the project. I have a problem with how to make the functionality of adding to another page and to the news database, which, when clicked, goes to favorites.

Comment: You'll have to create a collection which contains a document for every user, in this document you can either create another collection where you store all the articles that a user has favourited or just an array with the IDs of all the favourited articles. The later is recommended by me.

Comment: How can I implement the functionality of adding to a separate page on click?

Comment: I recommend you contact me on twitter, which you can find on my profile, so that we can have an in depth discussion on this topic.